# Does this graph have a name?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matroid-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n$ vertices and $\mathcal{T}$ be the set of all spanning trees of   $G$.

Consider the graph whose vertices are the elements of $\mathcal{T}$
and

$T, T' \in \mathcal{T}$ are connected by an edge if $|E(T)\cap E(T')| = n - 2 $

Does this graph have a name?

One can see that the graph is connected.  Are any of its other properties known?

Is there any literature on this graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen this called the *Tree Graph* of $G$. It has been investigated by a lot of authors. For example Cummings proved in "Hamilton circuits in tree graphs" IEEE Trans. Circuit Theory,13(1966), pp.82-90, that this graph is Hamiltonian.  Holzmann and Harary generalized this to tree graphs of matroids in ["On the Tree Graph of a Matroid"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2099712).

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about a name, but for starters see Lovasz "A homology theory for the spanning trees of a graph" http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/homology-span-tree.pdf